# Unusual date format (string) to datetime in AWS Redshift SQL

Tags: sql, csv, amazon-redshift

I am currently pulling data (.CSV) off this API that I built in Java.

One of the columns from my CSV table - "created_at" - is coming under the string format as the below:

[image]

Is there anyway I can transform this in Redshift SQL to datetime under the following format:

[image]

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Do you care about the timezone?

Comment: I do but will look into this as soon as this issue above is sorted. I will then use a different column from the table to relate / convert the transactions (this is a payment transactions table) to their original timezone - if that makes sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See if this helps (updated)

```
select cast('Thu Sep 12 17:58:46 BST 2019' as timestamp);
```

Or simply,

```
select 'Thu Sep 12 17:58:46 BST 2019':: timestamp
```

Comment: This works perfect on SQL but not Redshift SQL....When running the above on Redshift SQL I get the following:                                                                                   _"ERROR: [Amazon](500310) Invalid operation: syntax error at or 
near ","  Position: 142; Error Code: 500310 "_

Answer (score 0):

If you can live without the timezone, you can try:

```
select to_timestamp(left(str, 20) || right(str, 4), 'Dy Mon DD HH24:MI:SS YYYY')
from (select 'Thu Sep 12 17:58:46 BST 2019' as str) v;
```

Comment: I am getting the following error when running the above: 

"_ERROR: [Amazon](500310) Invalid operation: syntax error at or 
near ")"  Position: 127; Error Code: 500310_"

Comment: @Andre . . . Redshift doesn't support `values()`.  I tested that using Postgres.